# How to link two databases

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have two databases. But I have some data which depends on one another table. Now I want to link the two databases. when I change a specific column from a table of 1st database then I want to effect another column of 2nd table from another database. I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution.

Please give me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please **research** your solutions yourself..... we're not just *giving* you your solution,... some effort on your own is required! Look at SQL Server replication - search on Google or Bing and **read up on the feature**

Comment: Thats good one but I googled for one hour.Never find anything. Before that I find myself a solution which is create a function for that column (called computed column)to change 2nd table. i want to know whether there has any way to link 2 db like access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Triggers to change data in other database. But you should also consider using Stored Procedures if that feasible.

Both solutions require permissions to access other database. In my opinion best way to grant permissions if using triggers/stored procedures is certificates (great article [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html)).

Comment: Thanks Janis. If I  use function and use in computer column then how it will beheave? I need to insert data in another table into function. the code below.
`Create FUNCTION [dbo].[LC_Close](@LCStatus INT)

RETURNS INT

AS

BEGIN

 Case i.LCStatus
 when '3' then
 INSERT INTO ROSC.dbo.LCStatus
 ( DistrictID, UpazilaID, LCID, LCSl, Status, MemoNo)

 values
 (3, 89, 48, 3, 1, 'Test')

RETURN 
0
 END`
where Rosc is another databse and LCStatus is a table of Rosc. When the value is 3 then it will insert a row in LCStatus table.
Please correct me. Thanks

Comment: @Soulidentities you can not do any DML operations inside a function. So computed column will not work.